# How to add jenkinsfile parameter values

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my jenkinsfile, I have following params and would like to create a env variable that sums up these two params. How to do this?

```
parameters {
string(name: 'log_act_instances', defaultValue: '1')
string(name: 'log_arb_instances', defaultValue: '1')
}

environment {
log_instances = log_act_instances+log_arb_instances (Value should be 2 for log_instances)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the parameters from within the `params` map. You also need to convert the parameters to integers, because currently the `+` operator would return `11` and not `2` because they are both strings.

From within the `env` block, a parameter would be accessed and could be converted to an integer like:

```
params.log_act_instances.toInteger()
```

The full code would appear like:

```
environment {
  log_instances = "${params.log_act_instances.toInteger() + params.log_arb_instances.toInteger()}"
}
```

Comment: Does this needs some brackets or quotes? It is throwing error that it should be quoted. But when I out it in single quotes, it considers it as a string

Comment: @user312307 Yeah I forgot you have to cast both from string to integer, and then back to string, while keeping both in the same expression before the extra recast. Fixing now.